# Print logs on console for a fetch API called from javascript function in a HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to achieve a task here.
I have an endpoint being called from JavaScript function & I need capture the response of the html form post page in my console.log.

Problem:
If I use fetch API or xmlHttpRequest, I get a CORS error. Assuming that there is no way in resolving CORS on server-side, I want to know if there is a way to get the response and print in my console.log.

Note: I have used 'no-cors' header, but it gives me opaque response with status code as 0(null)
Note: I have used Allow Origin/Allow Method headers, but it does not help.

But, I need these values to be printed in my console or capture in a var or const as I need them for the next set of transactions.

Comment: CORS is a server issue. You can't do anything about it in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I have read about it. But in case I want to give a fix on client side as a hack. Is that achievable?

Comment: Client-side = browser. It's not achievable.

Comment: If you are using chrome you can disable cors security in the browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome, Please note that this is a `hack` not to be used normally

Comment: This is in official laptop. Will not be having privileges to do this.